# Data becoming undefined midway through the test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I want to render a header text only if keyData exists.

If I run the test against this component, I am able to see

that the data for keyData is definitely set.

Seeing following in debug:

```
keyData = Object{header: "keyInfoHeader"}
```

But it doesn't seem to render and end up with following error.

> Error: Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

But if I remove the check ({keyData &&) , it renders fine and able to get snapshot.

Why is this so?

I want to be able to test that it will only render if keyData exists

and unable to test it due to this. Please advice.

My Component

```
const MyComponent = ({
     data: {
       product: {
         all: {
           information: keyData
         },
       },
     },
   }) => (
  <div>
    {/* renders fine if I remove keyData */}
    {keyData && (
    <Element>
      {'header'}
    </Element>
    )}

    {/* when I reach this Element, keyData is now undefined in debugger.. how..  */}
    <Element/>
  </div>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

This is the test I am running against it.

```
describe('A Labels', () => {
  // there are other tests which uses this
  const defaultProps = {
    data: {
      product: {
        all: {},
      },
    },
  };

  const mountRender = props => mount(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />);

  it('should rr', () => {

    const rendered = mountRender({
      data: {
        product: {
          all: {
            information: {
              header: 'keyInfoHeader'
            }
          },
        },
      },
    });

    expect(mountRender().find('Element').first().props()).toMatchSnapshot();

  });
});
```